# How to get faster response from API REST using Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin

I´m brand new developer and I´m dealing now with Retrofit in Android connecting to a NASA API REST (json). The thing is when I code to get more than 90 registers (URL images), It´s not capable to get them.

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance!

My best

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL_APOD)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
```

Comment: likely it's required to adjust timeout values - while the code provided is nothing reproducible.

Comment: The response times have nothing to do with Retrofit, it's the internet or the API

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! My best.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to increase Retorfit timeouts like this:

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build()

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(URL_APOD)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(client)
    .build()
```

Comment: Thanks a million Andrei! At least I can list more registers.